# Swift 2 Ambiguous use of 'subscript' error

Tags: xcode, swift, swift2, ios9

After upgrading to new version of xcode/swift I am getting lots of 'ambiguous use of subscript' errors.

The code in question is below, with the lines causing errors labelled with comments. Any ideas?

```
  var exch: (AnyObject) = self.form.formValues().valueForKey(Static.exchange)!

    if (exch.count != nil) {

        if (exch.count==1) {
            ex = exch[0] as! Int // error

        } else if (exch.count==2) {
            var i1 = exch[0] as! Int //error
            var i2 = exch[1] as! Int //error
            var total = i1 + i2
            ex = total

        } else if (exch.count==3) {
            var i1 = exch[0] as! Int //error
            var i2 = exch[1] as! Int //error
            var i3 = exch[2] as! Int //error
            var total = i1 + i2 + i3
            ex = total

        } else {
            ex = 99

        }

    }
```

Comment: Is `exch` supposed to be an `NSArray`? If so, you need to cast it to an array first. In your code, the type of `exch` is `AnyObject` so the compiler can't tell what type it is and therefore what subscript function should be used.

Answer (score 1):

What is a type of `exch`? If it is an array of `AnyObject` change

```
var exch: (AnyObject)
```

to

```
var exch: [AnyObject]
```

Comment: @user2647092 Glad to hear this. Please do not forget to accept the answer if it was helpful :)

Comment: Thanks so much to save my lot of time.